# plotly line graph shows straight lines as time interval between lines is very small

Tags: python, python-3.x, plotly, plotly-dash, plotly-python

I am trying to plot some transitions from a log file. The issue seems that the interval between the transitions seems to be very small. less than 1 second or so.

This leads to the graph to look like this. As the x axis has 2 days timestamps:

[image: zoom out]

But when I zoom in I get something like this:

[image: zoom in]

What can I do to make it more user friendly? Apart from reducing the time interval in a frame.

Comment: you can evaluate the intervals between each two transmissions, if they are too large, add a sample with value None. This will make plotly create a gap around that None sample, so only closely related events would appear connected in the plot. Given the difference between bursts of transmissions (seconds/minutes) and the entire temporal horizon (days), you will always face that type of collapsing view